# Storing the value of ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()

Tags: sql-server, encryption, password-encryption, sql-server-2017

I am using the below query in SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

```
SELECT ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('xxyy','test@123')
```

When I run the above statement, it returned an encrypted password like `0x01000000EA686E7D1AED8C501B193A2F655368FC3EABA009082C90F58987DD0487833C62`

I wanted to store this in a table which contains a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field using a stored procedure, but insertion happens with a blank value instead of the encrypted password.

I used a `print` statement to acquire the value emitted by this function with in the SP. It returned some unreadable characters as below.

`됏㬷病譽快`
[image]

How to use `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` properly in order to insert the return value to a table field.

Comment: If you're wanting to store the value of `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` store it as a `varbinary(8000)`, that's the (maximum) return data type: [ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following Sql statement

```
CREATE TABLE #TempPassword (encPassword varbinary(250))
declare @encPwd varbinary(250)
set @encPwd = (SELECT ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('xxyy','test@123'))

insert into #TempPassword values (@encPwd)
select * from #TempPassword
```

Now the output after insert it is as shown below

```
encPassword
0x0100000023C4E9BFBC0F4319735ED2F0C76C2D857C114D96867711F1EE290AB2E7511961
```

Comment: No need to use `MAX`; as I mentioned in my comment above the maximum return type is `varbinary(8000)`.